# How can I invalidate and JWT token before the expiry time using java?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm trying to implement a logout functionality. We are using JWT tokens for authentication. But since JWT tokens become invalid only after they expire, even after the user logs out, if the old (unexpired) token is used, it works.
Is there a way to ensure that the JWT token is invalidated?

Comment: Generally speaking: no. That is now those work and how they are supposed to work. You can track the validity of a JWT in a database but then you will loose a lot of the benefits of JWTs if any services needs to contact the database to verify the token. At that point you can just use a session cookie instead.

Comment: As @luk2302 mentioned - you could invalidate JWT by tracking state of your tokens. But why? Just decrease lifespawn time of tokens. However, if you still want to invalidate tokens after logout action - you could store their state in Redis. Or cookies might be the option for this case

Comment: This is exactly one of the reasons why JWTs shouldn't be used to store sessions: https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to invalidate JWT, but you can decrease validity time.